# Get metadata of MP4/streaming URL in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4

I am showing MP4 videos in an app. How can I get metadata of the MP4?

http://www.ooklnet.com/files/368/368007/video.mp4

Like thumbnail URL, title, etc. I am mainly looking to get the middle frame of MP4 video.

Comment: Have you tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Comment: I tried it but i got illegal argumant exception . I thought it is for local mp4 stored in device and not streaming url . AM i wrong ?

Comment: I thought it would work with some external formats but I haven't used that class in a while. Are you opposed to using FFmpeg? Android doesn't provide any other mechanism for retrieving metadata from remote files so you will have to use an external library. I use FFmpeg to retrieve metadata from external files in my own project and it works great.